# Postman - Newman running from NodeJS

Tags: postman, newman

In order to save the response from postman API calls, I am executing Postman collection using newman run.

The collection runs when running using

```
newman run C:\TasteBud\NewMan\JSON-Order_collection.json --env-var unique_order_id=OD-06-07-I2Q5-JYRY5ARPN --environment C:\TasteBud\NewMan\EnvironmentJSON.json
```

However when I run the same collection as part of javascript or nodejs script.

```
node writeToFile.js
```

it throws error as node *"1⠄ JSONError in test-script  "*  refer attached image. I need to pass the auth token generated by login request to subsequent request. So I have variable assignment in the "test".

```
let response = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("auth_token", response.data.auth_token);
console.log(pm.response.json().data.auth_token);
```

Why cant I have "test" ? if no then how can I pass/set these environment variable for subsequent API call ?

Code inside writeToFile.js is here. [writeToFile.js](https://pastebin.com/W35RgfJX)

[image: Successful run using command line]

[image: Calling via NodeJS]

[image: Javascript in test to get auth-token]

Comment: see the response from the endpoint it seems like there is no response

Comment: use htmlextra  report its the best , it makes your life easier

Comment: Hi @PDHide, 
Thanks for your reply. The first call is supposed to get auth-token only. so no response. however, the test has code to pass the auth token to env variable for the subsequent request. 

Problem here is why the call fails. is there a better place to ask this question ?

Comment: the error is from pm.response.json() , it means there was no response from the endpoint . see for the first call where you get the token there will be a response that sends you the token . print that response and see whats wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use status code validation in your token generation. because every request is based on the token, if we receive negative status code, terminate the build.

> **postman.setNextRequest(null);**

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
if(responseCode.code === 200){
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("AT", jsonData.oauth2.accessToken);
console.log("AccessToken : " +jsonData.oauth2.accessToken);
}
else{
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
      console.log("Error generating user token");
    console.log("Status code : "+responseCode.code);
    console.log("Status description  : "+jsonData.statusDescr);
}
```